# Selenium iPhone Simulator Alternative for doing a Test Run

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, web, webdriver

I am using iPhone Simulator in MAC with Xcode to run my tests which I wrote, even if I code first time and if I want to test the code works or not I need to run in simulator is there is any alternative way to do it ? instead of running in simulator even to test a code before the actual Test runs ?

I use Google Chrome with User Agent as iPhone to identify components as my application renders based on the Browser agent.

My initial plan is to call Chrome with pre-defined Profiles and user agent extensions.

Kindly give your suggestions.

Comment: I would do it that way too. What other kind of alternative are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There are many emulators out there for the iPhone.  Configuring Chrome with User Agents is one of the quickest and easiest.

Maybe implementing your tests with a slicker tool may help reduce this burden?  I suggest you take a look at [iOS Driver](http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/).